# How to translate native SiteConfig with silverstripe-fluent

Tags: config, silverstripe, fluent, silverstripe-4

I'm using silverstripe 4 with silverstripe-fluent module. I can't translate native SiteConfig (site name and tagline/slogan) How do that ?

Thank for your help!

Aurélien

Comment: Please show us what you have tried :)

Comment: @Jones1220:  I have juste write my DataExtension as the [documentation](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/configuration/siteconfig/) write.
But i can't find the way to tell fluent to translate this fields (`FooterContent`, `SiteName` and `Slogan`)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Translating only specific variables.

Solved it simular:

YML (config.yml)

```
SilverStripe\SiteConfig\SiteConfig:
  extensions:
  - Pixelparker\Extensions\SiteConfigExtension
  - TractorCow\Fluent\Extension\FluentExtension
```

SiteConfigExtension.php

```
private static $translate = [
    'CookieMessage'
];
```

thats it.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to translate `SiteConfig`'s default `Title` and `Tagline` DB field, then you can apply both the Fluent extension and define the DB fields to be translated in a `.yml` configuration file, like this:

```
SilverStripe\SiteConfig\SiteConfig:
  extensions:
    - TractorCow\Fluent\Extension\FluentExtension
  translate:
    - Title
    - Tagline
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solved !**
Add `TractorCow\Fluent\Extension\FluentExtension` in `Silverstripe\SiteConfig\SiteConfig` :

```
---
Name: myproject
---
SilverStripe\Core\Manifest\ModuleManifest:
  project: app
Silverstripe\SiteConfig\SiteConfig:
  extensions:
    - TractorCow\Fluent\Extension\FluentExtension
    - CustomSiteConfig
```

and extends `FluentExtension` instead of `DataExtension` in your config extension class :

```
use SilverStripe\Forms\FieldList;
use SilverStripe\Forms\HTMLEditor\HTMLEditorField;
use TractorCow\Fluent\Extension\FluentExtension;


class CustomSiteConfig extends FluentExtension
{

    private static $db = [
        'FooterContent' => 'HTMLText'
    ];

    public function updateCMSFields(FieldList $fields)
    {
        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main",
            new HTMLEditorField("FooterContent", "Footer Content")
        );
        parent::updateCMSFields($fields);
    }
}
```